# Is there a limit to the number of routes you can have?

Tags: mailgun

Is there a limit to the number of routes you can define for a Mailgun account? I am planning to have approximately 5,000 different routes and processing 100,000 inbound messages per month.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for limits for an account, not directly programming related.

Answer (score 2):

I contacted MailGun support directly. The answer is the default limit is 5,000 routes, but if you need more, contact support.